# Boolean logic in SQL

Tags: sql

I have to do the following by adding a check constraint on the table:

In Tenants, if LeaseExpirationDate isn’t NULL then it must be later than LeaseStartDate.

I am just wondering , can I use the folowing in SQL?

P: LeaseExpirationDate isn't null
T: LeaseExpirationDate is later than LeaseStartDate

P->T==-P OR T

Truth table

```
P     T      P->T=-P OR X
T      F             F
F      U            T
T      T             T
```

I am not sure if we can do the latter with three valued logic, but it looks like it works given the conditions.

Answer (score 2):

Take advantage of SQL's three-valued logic and the fact that a check constraint needs to not be `FALSE`, rather than be `TRUE`, to pass:

```
CHECK (LeaseExpirationDate > LeastStartDate)
```

If `LeaseExpirationDate` is `NULL`, then the whole condition evaluates as `UNKNOWN`. Which isn't `FALSE` and so the constraint isn't violated.

Comment: For the following one, we do need boolean logic right?:

Comment: If LastRentPaidDate in Tenants is the current date, then RentOverdue must be FALSE.